# Netbeans update fail

Tags: windows, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have no problem in my internet connection. But getting every time this screen when I try to update netbeans plugins or IDE itself.

[image: Window titled "NetBeans IDE Installer". Text in upper portion: "Welcome to the NetBeans IDE Plugin Installer. The installer will download, verify and then install the selected plugins." Text in lower portion: "Checking for updates failed. Check your network connection, verify that your proxy settings are configured correctly in the NetBeans IDE, or try again later."]

Even OS reintallation doesn't fix this issue. Getting same error again and again. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 17):

**In Netbeans**

Go to

> 1. Tools->Plugins->Settings

and

> 2. Add a new one or change the URL of "JAX-RPC" to the one referred below
>
> URL: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Comment: after updating NetBeans, it stopped working. I had to reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

Netbeans 8.0.2/Tools/Plugins/Settings.... found a bad url ie URL: http://netbeans.i2m.dk/updates.xml

Unchecked the Active column for "I2M Update Center" and the "Check for Updates" now works.

Comment: I also fixed this problem in the same way by unchecking the "Netbeans SQE" update centre, as the link was broken (also Netbeans 8.0.2).

Comment: Solved my problem, too. Was a broken update center link by yet another plugin. Hence, NetBeans' warning is too unspecific.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried every solution and no ones worked for me, but...something did it.

I changed every url in **Tool > Plugins > Settings** from **http** to **https**.

Example:

```
Name: Certified Plugins
URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.2/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
```

To:

```
Name: Certified Plugins
URL: https://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.2/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
```

And finally I can update my plugins and obtain the list of newest plugins.

Comment: I did but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Are you behind a proxy? If yes, you can change your settings at **`Tools -> Options -> General (Proxy Settings)`**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firewalls? May be its blocked by your firewall,

try to check the blocked applications.

**Update**

probably yes, because Kaspersky most of time will
 block without notice or accidentally might be 
blocked. so better try to check blocked application lists in kasperksy.
Check this links might help you to solve:

http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208285204

http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2012/settings/firewall?print=true&qid=208284433

Comment: I have Kaspersky Internet Security. Maybe this blocking NB.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Netbeans log - messages.log file - for details of the error!

Example locations of the file:

Linux: ~/.netbeans/7.3/var/log/messages.log

Windows: c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3\var\log\

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a late reply, however, i just experienced the same issue today. I went to Tools > Options > General, and chose "No Proxy". Hit "Apply and Ok". Instead of trying to update again, i just closed netbeans completely, relaunched it and it went to detect updates automatically. All went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I have one more solution to it.

If you locate **Tools -> Plugins -> settings** on your NetBeans IDE And then uncheck the **Plugin portal** and add **https instead of http** on **certified plugin and NetBeans distribution**.

Then try to update.

Hope it'll work for you.