# NetBeans - Unable to connect to the Update Center

Tags: netbeans, windows-10

I can't update NetBeans, I always get "*Unable to connect to the Update Center*".

I already checked the windows firewall settings:

[image]

I also checked the proxy, I get a green checkmark:

[image]

What else can I try?

I am using NetBeans 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

Comment: I have the same environment as you (Build 201609300101 on Windows-10) and **Help > Check for Updates** works for me, with the response is _Your IDE is up to date! There are no updates available_. Two simple things you can do: [1] Check the NetBeans log for errors (**View > IDE Log**). [2] Pick some random plugin and install it to see if that works/fails, to possibly gain more insight on the problem. To do that: **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > Install**. If that also fails check the log for errors. You can uninstall the plugin afterwards.

Comment: View->IDE Log is of much help - but the message "Your IDE is up to date!" is sometimes misleading, because it will appear also when you actually remove all the update servers from the servers list..

Answer (score 5):

Proxy settings were NOT the problem for me.

I'm running NetBeans 11.0, and see that there are 4 default "Update Centers" configured. Having nothing to do with Proxy settings, I discovered that the "NetBeans Plugin Portal" URL was failing `https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/plugins/11.1/catalog.xml.gz`, and the last time this site was successfully checked was on 4/20/21.

My solution was to deselect that Update Center, and added the 11.0 archive site instead:

`http://plugins.archive.librebeans.org/catalogue/11.0/catalog.xml`

[image]

Now I can update/install plugins as expected. Maybe this is the solution for you too.

Answer (score 1):

there is a number of similar questions from long ago (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664874/netbeans-update-fail)), and the suggestions are mainly about misconfigured proxy.
in my case, looking at the IDE log file revealed the following stack trace:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl]: Timeout while opening connection to http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-metro-lib.nbm
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.NetworkAccess$Task$1.run(NetworkAccess.java:111)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Timeout while opening connection to http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-metro-lib.nbm
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.NetworkAccess$Task$1.run(NetworkAccess.java:131)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl]: Cannot access http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-metro-lib.nbm
java.io.IOException: Cannot access http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-metro-lib.nbm
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl.copy(InstallSupportImpl.java:981)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl.doDownload(InstallSupportImpl.java:733)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl.doDownload(InstallSupportImpl.java:661)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl.access$600(InstallSupportImpl.java:92)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl$1.call(InstallSupportImpl.java:172)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.InstallSupportImpl$1.call(InstallSupportImpl.java:144)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Because I thought that was nothing wrong with my proxy settings (no proxy is selected, and connection is tested OK), i searched and search, getting even into the NetBeans code, trying in vain to find some hidden Timeout property. Indeed there is a place in the code ([AutoupdateSettings.getOpenConnectionTimeout](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/tip/autoupdate.services/src/org/netbeans/modules/autoupdate/services/InstallSupportImpl.java) which seems to correspond to plugin.manager.connection.timeout property) which sets a timeout - yet i couldn't make it work (mucking with .properties files in ~/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.2/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/autoupdate)

In the end the only workaround I found was to download the NBM file mentioned in the stack trace manually. It seems that it was either indeed my firewall (an antivirus check?), or the file was just too large in itself and would cause the timeout because of this. Or the overloaded server. Anyway.

Fortunately, it is possible to install the downloaded file through Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugins, even though that plugin already is installed. Doing this the update process continued normally (although there was another timeout later - so I repeated the above procedure) and eventually completed.

The above plugins, for which I had to do manual install, were METRO 2.0 and JAXB 2.2