# Netbeans 8.0.2 won't start after updating

Tags: netbeans-8

recently I was able to update Netbeans 8.0.2 by using this guide for changing the update- url:
[Netbeans update fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664874/netbeans-update-fail)

After changing the url I installed all ( several douzen ) offered updates and restarted the IDE.
Now it shows the start- screen and disappears. That's all.

What may I be supposed to do to make it work again ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to start NetBeans from the console and see if there's any helpful output.

Comment: The output is:  Unknown option -L-XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Comment: Those parameters are defined in etc/netbeans.conf and they start with a J not an L. So correct would be -J-XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Comment: Apologies, there is no such entry within the .conf file. I looked into it and let the editor search for -L and for 384m without any result. I let Total Commander look into all files within the main directory for those two terms without result. Within the .conf- file there is the following entry: 

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

Comment: I found that line: -L-XX:MaxPermSize=384m only within one file called netbeans which has no file-extension within the bin directory and I changed it to your premise. Now it looks so: netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:MaxPermSize=384m ${netbeans_default_options}". After that the console still tells me: Unknown option -L-XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Answer (score 0):

I ended by un- & re-installing the IDE.